# JQUERY to filter input in a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie to jquery and javascript so this may be a silly question

I have a textfield and i would like to filter the input

so it will only let the usesr enter in [A-Z] chacters and also if the length of [A-Z] has reached 3 it then also disables the user from entereing any more characters

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that "monitors" the input field. Something like:

```
 $('#yourfield').change(function() {
     $val = $(this).val();
  if($val.length() > 2) $(this).attr('disabled', true)
 // so on, just to give you some ideas
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GLXuv/7/

```
$('#sexyInput').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''));

    if($(this).val().length >= 3) $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways an input form can be populated by a user:

1. User types in the form.
2. User pastes in the form.

This requires binding two separate events:

```
$('.numbers-only').keypress(function(e) {
    // Allow only keys [A-Za-z] and enter
    if (e.which !== 13 && ((e.which < 65 || e.which > 90) && (e.which < 97 || e.which > 122)) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}).bind('paste', function() {
    var el = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // replace anything that isn't a number with ''
        $(el).val($(el).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''));
    }, 100);
});
```